# How to generate a sort key from a Collator in Javascript & Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, indexing, unicode

The Unicode's ICU standard (International Components for Unicode) says that Unicode collations can be used in two ways: either to **compare** two strings (`compare(s1,s2)` method in ICU C++) to know their relative order; or to generate a **sort key** for any given string (`getSortKey()`), which is needed when building and sorting an index of multiple strings, like in a database. See the docs:

- ICU's [Compare](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/collation/api.html#compare) section,
- ICU's [GetSortKey](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/collation/api.html#getsortkey) section.

In Javascript and Node.js, there is [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) class that implements the [compare(s1,s2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/compare) method, similar to what's in ICU. However, **this class does NOT provide the other method: for sort key generation**. Questions:

1. Why the `getSortKey` method is missing in Javascript's Collator?
2. Are there any plans to add this method in the future?
3. Till then, is there any **substitute** (a package or whatever) that can be used to **generate sort keys** in JS/Node.js for arbitrary Unicode strings and arbitrary collations?

Searching for "unicode sort keys" and "collations" in NPM & Google don't yield any sensible results. The only package that has anything to do with sort keys is [unicode-collation-algorithm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unicode-collation-algorithm2), which seems to be using sort keys internally in the source code, but doesn't expose any API for this, and doesn't accept arbitrary collations.

Comment: In case you get no satisfactory answer here: https://github.com/tc39/ecma402